# docker compose using old code even after purge and rebuild

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, blazor-webassembly

Running on windows, I have a web API (ASP.net core) and a Blazor WASM App that should communicate with the API. Since I'm trying to learn docker I started by creating a dockerfile for both projects and create two completely separate docker images (Docker Desktop 4.28.0).

The App in the image uses nginx. Additionally I use a volume to share and store some data. If I run my API and App this way everything works fine. Now I wanted to switch to using `docker compose` instead of two completely separate images/containers. The dockerfiles are in the two projects subfolders in relation to the `compose.yaml`. Now getting the images and containers up and running is not a problem, however code changes in my Blazor App are simply not reflected now - no matter what I do the Blazor App remains just an old version. If I just use `docker build` without using `compose` for the App everything is fine and the new code runs.

I realized that if I just use `docker compose up` or `docker compose up --build` there are cached files used which might be the cause for this issue. Following the many similar issues I found on SO (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37685581/how-to-get-docker-compose-to-use-the-latest-image-from-repository), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77670717/docker-compose-is-not-updating-source-code) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31750386/docker-compose-not-showing-any-changes-to-code)) I tried `docker compose up -d --force-recreate` without success. Also running these commands

```
docker compose stop
docker compose rm -f
docker compose pull   
docker compose up -d
```

didn't change anything. Then I tried to completely delete any docker cache by using `docker system prune -a` and rebuild afterwards - again the old code was obviously running, even though I saw while running `docker compose up -d --force-recreate` that there were no cached files used during the process. As a last resort I also tried "Clean/Purge data" from the Troubleshoot menu in docker desktop and also "Reset to factory defaults" - still no success. Repeatedly I also deleted the bin and obj folders from my Visual Studio project because I thought maybe it might actually be a very weird Visual Studio issue - of course that wasn't helpful either.

Where does docker even find this old code after purging everthing? Are there still cached files "hiding" somewhere? Is there something wrong with my compose.yaml? I'm considering now completely removing docker from my PC and reinstalling but I guess there must be a simpler solution to fix this.

Here is my docker compose.yaml:

```
services:
  myapp:
    build: 
      /myapp/myapp
    ports:
      - "8000:5000"
  myapi:
    build: 
      /myapi/myapi
    ports:
      - "32771:8080"
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: C:/mysource/_data/
        target: /app/data/
```

The dockerfile of my Blazor App is:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build

RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y python3
RUN dotnet workload install wasm-tools

WORKDIR /src
COPY myapp.csproj .
RUN dotnet restore myapp.csproj
COPY . .
RUN dotnet build myapp.csproj -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish myapp.csproj -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM nginx:alpine AS final
WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY --from=publish /app/publish/wwwroot .
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

EXPOSE 8080
```